# Unexpected query results with multiple joins - mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have a multi-table setup to handle online purchase transactions. The main table I'm getting data from is a purchase activity table. It contains ShipAcctID, which connects it to an addresses table, and AcctID, which connects it to a users table - sort of. The AcctID field is a reference to the user's account ID, which is stored in the users table, but what I need to return is their shipping address, which is connected in the addresses table via the customer_id field.

To try to clear that up, here's what the tables actually look like.

**Purchases table**

```
ID   |   PurchAmt   |   AcctID    | ShipAddrID
================================================
1    |   30.99      |   25        |  420
2    |   45.22      |   31        |  209
```

**Users table**

```
ID   |   Name       
=================================
25   |   Anastasia Beaverhausen   
31   |   Charles Beaverhausen
45   |   Bennie Beaverhausen
```

**Addresses table**

```
ID   |   customer_id   | name                     |  address          
==========================================================================
300  |   25            | Anastasia Beaverhausen   | 123 Park Avenue  
209  |   31            | Charles Beaverhausen     | 500 5th Avenue   
420  |   45            | Bennie Beaverhausen      | 500 North Michigan Avenue
```

What I need to do is return something like this:

```
PurchaseID   |  PurchAmt  | billname                   |billAddress        |shipName           | shipaddress
====================================================================================================================================
1            |  30.99     | Anastasia Beaverhausen     |123 Park Avenue    |Bennie Beaverhausen  |500 North Michigan Avenue
```

So I need to get the billaddress by joining purchases to addresses via the purchases.AcctID = addresses.customer_id relationship; then get the shipaddress by joining purchases directly to addresses via the purchases.ShipAddrID = addresses.id relationship. It makes sense in my head, anyway. But when I run the query, I get multiple rows per purchase ID, like this:

```
PurchActvtyID | billName           | billAddress1             |shipName         |   shipAddress1
==================================================================================================================================
1535    |       Anastasia Beaverhausen | 123 Park Avenue          |Bennie Beaverhausen  | 500 North Michigan Avenue
1535    |       Bennie Beaverhausen    | 500 North Michigan Avenue  | Bennie Beaverhausen   | 500 North Michigan Avenue
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I'm sure it's probably something to do with which kind of join to use, but I can't seem to get the correct results no matter which kind I try. Here's my query:

```
SELECT p.PurchActvtyID, a1.name AS billName, a1.address1 AS billAddress1, a2.name AS shipName, a2.address1 AS shipAddress1
FROM arrc_PurchaseActivity p
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_customers_addresses a1 ON p.AcctID = a1.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_customers_addresses a2 ON p.ShipAddrID = a2.id

ORDER BY p.PurchActvtyID ASC
```

**EDITS**

results of Stephen's query:

```
PurchActvtyID  |    billName   |    shipName   |    billAddress  |  shipAddress
========================================================================================

1535  | Esther Strom | Esther Strom |123 Park Avenue | 500 North Michigan Avenue

1535  | Esther Strom | Esther Strom |500 North Michigan Avenue |500 North Michigan Avenue
```

The reason for the name being different from what I showed in my example of desired outcome is that your query is pulling the name from the users table, which isn't accurate - the user name isn't necessarily the same as the billing or shipping name asssociated with a given user. This is why I need to pull those values from the addresses table, not the users table.

Comment: deleted my answer because I was obviously barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Have you checked for duplicated data?

Comment: @Stephen - yes, there is no duplicated data. There is a single purchase record - see the PurchActvtyID field in the results I posted above - that field is the primary key for the purchases table. So for some reason, rather than displaying a single row per purchase record, with columns for billname, billaddress, shipname, and shipaddress, it's showing two separate results with all those columns, and inaccurate data in the second row (the first one is correct.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did get an answer to this on experts-exchange. All I needed to do was use a group by clause. So my query now looks like this:

```
SELECT p.PurchActvtyID, a1.name AS billName, a1.address1 AS billAddress1, a2.name AS shipName, a2.address1 AS shipAddress1
FROM arrc_PurchaseActivity p
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_customers_addresses a1 ON p.AcctID = a1.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_customers_addresses a2 ON p.ShipAddrID = a2.id
GROUP BY p.PurchActvtyID
ORDER BY p.PurchActvtyID ASC
```

Comment: This will only return one "billing" address per purchase, but it won't necessarily **be** the billing address - it could be any of the delivery addresses, as well. Either add `a1.billing` to the `order by` clause, or add `a1.billing = 1` to the join clause for the billing address, to ensure that the address reported as the billing address actually is the billing address.

Answer (score 1):

Although there aren't duplicates as such, you can have multiple addresses for a single customer ID - this is what appears to be happening in the example, as a single purchase (1535) is returning multiple billing addresses (both 123 Park Avenue and 500 North Michigan Avenue).

Normally, a customer *could* have many billing addresses (over time), although there is normally only one billing address per transaction. I therefore suggest adding a BillAddrID field to arrc_PurchaseActivity (if it doesn't already have one), and changing the linkage to jos_customers_addresses alias a1 to be `p.BillAddrID = a2.id`.

Alternatively, you may want (or already have) only one billing address per customer, in which case you should add a billing address ID field to your customer table (users, in the question), and then change the query to link from the purchase table to the customer table, and then from the customer's billing address ID to the address table, to return a single billing address for the transaction.

EDIT, following comments:

The following query should resolve the issue of multiple addresses being returned on the billing alias:

```
SELECT p.PurchActvtyID, a1.name AS billName, a1.address1 AS billAddress1, a2.name AS shipName, a2.address1 AS shipAddress1
FROM arrc_PurchaseActivity p
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_customers_addresses a1 ON p.AcctID = a1.customer_id and a1.billing = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_customers_addresses a2 ON p.ShipAddrID = a2.id
ORDER BY p.PurchActvtyID ASC
```

Comment: Mark, in this case, there can only be one billing address per customer, and it's always associated with the addresses.customer_id = users.id relationship. I cannot make any changes to the table structure; this database belongs to a client, and it already contains thousands of records worth of historical data, so there's no way to add a new field at this point.

Comment: @EmmyS, how are you supposed to distinguish between billing addresses and delivery addresses? Both will exist for the same customer in the address table.

Comment: There's a field in the table called billing; if it's set to 0 it's a shipping address; if it's set to 1 it's a billing address.

Comment: @EmmyS, that's your answer: add `and a1.billing = 1` to the join condition for `jos_customers_addresses a1`. I have updated my answer with an appropriately amended query.

Answer (score 1):

To create the output you want you only need two tables:
**Purchases** table
**Addresses** table
However, you need to join to the **Addresses** table twice:
Once for the **Billing Address**
Once for the **Shipping Address**

```
SELECT
t1.ID       as PurchaseID,
t1.PurchAmt as PurchAmt,
t2.name     as billname,
t2.address  as billaddress,
t3.name     as shipname,
t3.address  as shipaddress
FROM Purchases t1
INNER JOIN Addresses t2
        ON t1.AcctID
         = t2.customer_id
INNER JOIN Addresses t3
        ON t1.ShipAddrID
         = t3.ID
```

The **1st INNER JOIN** links to the **billing** information
The **2nd INNER JOIN** links to the **shipping** information

Comment: That's pretty much what I had done on the initial post, and had people tell me I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think there's a reason to join the same table twice based on your criteria...

Try:

```
SELECT p.PurchActvtyID, a1.name AS billName, a1.address1 AS billAddress1, a1.name AS shipName, a1.address1 AS shipAddress1
FROM arrc_PurchaseActivity p
LEFT OUTER JOIN jos_customers_addresses a1 ON p.AcctID = a1.customer_id AND p.ShipAddrID = a1.id

ORDER BY p.PurchActvtyID ASC
```

Note - I work with SQL Server, I'm assuming syntax will work with MySQL.

Edit:

I suspect it's happening because you are doing two left outer joins to the same table on different criteria.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How am I getting the values that I have listed as a2.* if you're not creating a join on a table labeled a2?

Comment: @EmmmyS - You are joining the same table twice.  Instead of listing two joins, you list one join with two conditions.

Comment: But that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want one join that needs two conditions to be true. I want two separate joins, each that has a single condition - they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @EmmyS - I don't think you understand the way the `JOIN` results work.  They are **NOT** mutually exclusive, otherwise you would have `NULL` for either your a1 or a2 fields in the query.  The fact that you are requesting 2 result sets through two `JOIN`s to the same table is why you are getting multiple lines.